# Layer reprojection confusion

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Here is a screenshot of a portion of my csv: [image: CSV]

I've been working in QGIS for a few years now, but I have been horrible at reprojecting layers since forever. I have two layers, a shapefile and a .csv, and even when I run them both through 'reproject layer', they remain at radically different scales, if they're visible at all. Is there a specific CRS needed for my .csv even if it doesn't specify one? If so, how do I get my shapefile into *that* CRS? I understand this a beginner question, but it's vexxed me for years and no amount of Youtube tutorials have been able to show me.

Problem:
Layers at radically different scales/locations spatially

Attempted Solutions:

1. Reproject layer dialog box
2. Set CRS dialog box
3. Assign CRS dialog box
4. Various transformations

Comment: Sounds to me like one of your layers has the wrong CRS assigned, one of the rare cases you need to set the CRS of said layer.

Comment: A projection doesn't have anything to do with scale; it's perfectly possible to have two datasets with different scales in the same projection

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the csv? Just a few lines.

Comment: @Alešinar - Just edited the OP - thanks!

Comment: What you state is the problem *isn't* the problem. *That's* the problem. In order to have an answerable Question, you need to choose one of your solutions and provide details (including the coordinate reference and range of X,Y values in each layer), reporting on the steps you took and the result .

Comment: @nmtoken But if my shapefile is at 1:5000 (roughly), and my csv is at 1:2, and both only appear (independently) when I press 'zoom to layer', I definitely messed up somewhere, right?

Comment: It's possible indeed.  What is information is in the shapefile .prj file?  And are you using the state plane coordinates or the latitude/longitude values in the csv

Comment: As far as I know, csv-s do not have CRS defined as it is just a table. So you have to figure out in which coordinate system are the coordinates stored in csv and then tell QGIS how to display the points. Shapefile should have CRS defined, but it is possible that it is not. In this case, you have to find this out too. Only then can you reproject into a common coordinate system and overlay.

Comment: @Alešinar  Ooooooh, this sounds like the key! Can coordinate systems not be totally changed? I was thinking That if I have two items in CRS A and C, if I changed them both to B, that'll work. Is this not how reprojecting works?

Comment: The actual data coordinates (latitude and longitude in your table) can be in the different coordinate systems as the dataset represents itself to be in. When you import the csv in qgis, there is no way qgis can know by itself in which coordinate system the coordinates in csv are. You have to define it. Once you define it you can reproject it into a different coordinate system as qgis will know which transformation between coordiante systems to use.